# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined - Undefined values but I don't know why

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to flip a card when it is being clicked. 
I did a console.log(card[i]) just before addEventListener and it works fine but error appeared on the console.log after that addEventListener.

The error I got is: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

These are my code

```js
var card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
var cardInner = document.querySelectorAll('.card-inner');
var cardBack = document.querySelectorAll('.card-back');


for (var i=0; i < card.length; i++) {
    console.log(card[i]);      // works fine
    // when a card is clicked
    card[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        // flip THAT card
        console.log(card[i]);    // undefined value 
        card[i].style.perspective = "500px";
        cardInner[i].style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
        cardInner[i].style.transition = "all 0.5s"; 
        cardBack[i].style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";

    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Memory Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <section class="box">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-inner">
                <div class="card-front"></div>
                <div class="card-back"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-inner">
                <div class="card-front"></div>
                <div class="card-back"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        
        
        

    </section>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have this function wrapped in DOMContentLoaded listener? (window.onload) It might be because your divs are not created when you try to assign them listeners and styles. DOMContentLoaded listener is fired after all content is created.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are creating a *closure*, and you are closing over the wrong variable.

Each of the inner functions you are creating will have 'closed' over the local variable `i`.  This means that this local variable will be kept alive after the loop finishes and the inner functions will be able to access it.  However, it is important to note that the inner functions have access to the variable `i`, not the value `i` had when the function was created.  The on-click event listeners won't fire until after the loop has finished, but once the loop finishes, `i` will have value `card.length`, and of course `card[i]` will be undefined because `i` points to an element off the end of your `card` array.

What you need to do instead is to 'close' over each value of `i` separately.  One way to do this is to create another function and pass the value of `i` to this function:

```js
function addEventListenerToCard(index) {
    card.addEventListener('click', function(){
        // flip THAT card
        console.log(card[index]);
        card.style.perspective = "500px";
        cardInner[index].style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
        cardInner[index].style.transition = "all 0.5s"; 
        cardBack[index].style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";

    });
}

for (var i=0; i < card.length; i++) {
    console.log(card[i]);      // works fine
    // when a card is clicked
    addEventListenerToCard(i);
}
```

In this case, each call to `addEventListenerToCard` creates a new scope for the parameter `index`, and this parameter doesn't get changed, so each event listener keeps track of which card it is associated to.

You could also try using `Array.forEach` instead of a loop:

```js
card.forEach(function (cardElement, index) {
    console.log(card[index]);      // can also write "console.log(cardElement);" here
    // when a card is clicked
    card[index].addEventListener('click', function(){
        // flip THAT card
        console.log(card[index]);    // should no longer be an undefined value 
        card[index].style.perspective = "500px";
        cardInner[index].style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
        cardInner[index].style.transition = "all 0.5s"; 
        cardBack[index].style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
    });
});
```

Comment: Does the second parameter in all forEach function represent the **index** value? Just that we can create any params name but the value of that param is always the **index** of the array? Did I understand right

Comment: @WilsonTeh: yes, the second parameter in the function passed to `forEach` is the index of the element within the array.  It doesn't have to be named `index`.

Answer (score 0):

Luke answered perfectly an alternative solution is use `event.target` in your `addEventListener`

```js
var card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');    

for (var i=0; i < card.length; i++) {
       // console.log(card[i]);      // works fine
    // when a card is clicked
    card[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
        var elem=event.currentTarget;
        var cardInner = elem.querySelector('.card-inner');
        var cardBack = elem.querySelector('.card-back');
        

        // flip THAT card
        elem.style.perspective = "500px";
        cardInner.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
        cardInner.style.transition = "all 0.5s"; 
        cardBack.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";

        
    });
}
```

```css
.card{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
margin:5px;
}

.card-inner{
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.card-front{
margin:5px;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:green;
}

.card-back{
margin:5px;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Memory Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <section class="box">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-inner">
                <div class="card-front"></div>
                <div class="card-back"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-inner">
                <div class="card-front"></div>
                <div class="card-back"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        

    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That wouldn't quite work, as the questioner uses the `cardInner` and `cardBack` arrays in the event listener as well.

Comment: @LukeWoodward you have right, my fault, I have updated the answer putting the correct working code.

Comment: That still won't work, sorry. `cardInner` and `cardBack` are arrays, despite their names not being plural.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I have added a snippet, as you can see it works perfectly.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that you had moved the declaration of `cardInner` and `cardBack` inside your event handler.

Comment: @LukeWoodward No problem!